# How can i size a div correctly in between two absolute positioned panels

Tags: android, css, css-position

I'm trying to do something like the code bellow in my app, which i want to work inside of mobile browsers, the idea is that the content of the page stays between 2 absolute positioned containers,  and should scroll if it doesn't fit one is the title bar and one a keyboard element.

This code works well when using chrome dev tools to emulate a mobile it also works on Chrome browser for iPhones and Android, and seems to work in the apple browser (whatever that is) but the Samsung one doesn't seem to work, and the content just carries on under the keyboard without scrolling I'm using DVH for the height because phone browsers don't report 100vh intuitively, and this felt like a good approach, but is there a better way, or a way to get this to work on all key phone browsers?

```
<html>
<style>
.bar {
  width: 100vw;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 40px;
  background: #000000;
}
.content {
  margin-top: 45px;
  display: block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: calc(100dvh - 445px);
}

.keyboard {
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 400px;
  background: green;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="bar">
Top
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div>fish</div>
  <div>fish</div>
  <div>fish</div>
  <div>fish</div>
  <div>fish</div>
  <div>fish</div>
  <div>fish</div>
  <div>fish</div>
  <div>fish</div>
  <div>fish</div>
  <div>fish</div>
  <div>fish</div>
  <div>fish</div>
  <div>fish</div>
  <div>fish</div>
  <div>fish</div>
  <div>fish</div>
  <div>Cheese</div>
</div>
<div class = "keyboard">
Keyboard
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: caniuse.com reports that Sumsung internet does not support dvh (and neither does Firefox).

Comment: @AHaworth indeed I understand this to be the case, my question is really how can i achieve what i am trying to do better, or is there no way?

Comment: Please edit your answer and use the snippet tool `<>` to post your html and css.